# Part of profile page is some other language

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I look at my profile the lower tabs (resumo respostas .......  votos) are in some other language where as the upper tabs are in English. Looks like a bug.

[image]

**Edit:**

It back to normal and everything is in English.

Comment: Thats actually cool :p

Comment: Can't reproduce it yet, but we're looking into it...

Comment: @abbyhairboat It back to normal now and looks fine. Strange

Comment: Others are seeing it across the network, too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250194/portuguese-tab-names-on-profile-page

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the issue was resolved.